# visual composer text block bug

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I would like to ask if there is anyone who was facing simmilar or exactly this problem.
Yesterday was everything working well, but today when i was trying to insert text from word to wordpress text block(classic text editor), i wasn't able to select Header1 or Paragraph or anything, this dropdown window is not working.

This issue appeared on all wordpress pages i have with version of 4.8.1, it has affected visual composer as well as site origin  page builders.

How can i fix this?
[SEE SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLLDR.png)

Comment: UPDATE:  i tried two more websites which is totaly different themes and plugins,  they share same WP version 4.8.1 , visual composer seem to have problem with this version.

Comment: This is also happening on other webpaged with Site origin or visual composer. This is happening since wordpress update 4.8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it is confirmed now, all my sites are using Visual composer and all are having same issue after 4.8.1 . i installed 1 site with wordpress 4.8 and its start working. we have to wait until update from visual composer.

Comment: Siteorigin just updated plugins, confirming it's working, gotta wait for visual composer update.

Answer (score 3):

Quick fix until an update comes out.

Add this bit to your functions.php file.

```
function your_function_name() {
  echo '
  <style>
    .mce-container.mce-panel.mce-floatpanel.mce-menu.mce-menu-align { 
      z-index: 999999999 !important;
    }
  </style>';
}

add_action('admin_head', 'your_function_name');
```

Comment: Thank You for reply, the visual composer update fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok a bit simpler fix is to add this to your admin css:

```
.mce-container, .mce-container-body {
    z-index: 100000 !important;
}
```

Even lazier way is to use something like `http://coffee2code.com/wp-plugins/add-admin-css/` and add it there. I think this is fixed in newest version of VC.